# Deleted Items Reappearing in ArgoUML

Tags: argouml

I am using ArgoUML v0.34 to draw some class diagrams.

I am trying to delete some class attributes.

Unfortunately, if I delete the attributes (by clicking on them, then pressing delete), they will initially disappear, but reappear if I save and re-open the document.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The convention in ArgoUML is that Delete just removes an object from the diagram.  You need to use Ctrl/Delete to remove something from the model as opposed to just a diagram.